# Can I listen to music from my iPhone with a Plantronics Discovery 665 Headset?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

The headset supports the "Headset" and "Hands-Free" profiles.

I can make phone calls with it, but when I play music, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

No.  In order to do music, your Bluetooth headset must support A2DP Streaming Audio (it must support the A2DP profile).